# How to implement close , close all and close other tabs features on right click of tab-header in Extjs?

Tags: javascript, extjs

How to implement close , close all and close other tabs features on right click of tab-header in Extjs?

```
{
    xtype: 'tabpanel',
    region: 'center',
    reference: 'tabPanelRef',
    items: [{
        tab-1
    },{
        tab-2
    },{
        tab-3
    }],

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [example fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/28bo) using the [TabCloseMenu](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.ux.TabCloseMenu.html) plugin.  By including the plugin in your `tabpanel`, the `close`, `close all` and `close other` functions appear by right-clicking on the tab header.

```
Ext.define('ExampleTabs', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    xtype: 'reorderable-tabs',

    requires: [
        'Ext.ux.TabCloseMenu',
        'Ext.ux.TabReorderer'
    ],

    plugins: [
        'tabreorderer',
        'tabclosemenu'
    ],

    defaults: {
        closable: true
    },

    items: [{
        title: 'Tab 0 - fixed',
        html: "Cannot reorder or close this",
        reorderable: false,
        closable: false

    }, {
        title: 'Tab 1',
        html: 'Tab 1'
    }, {
        title: 'Tab 2',
        html: 'Tab 2'
    }, {
        title: 'Tab 3',
        html: 'Tab 3'
    }, {
        title: 'Tab 4',
        html: 'Tab 4'
    }],

});
```